# How do I show that $p\mid {p\choose k}$ if $gcd(p,k)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose we need to show that $p \mid {p\choose k}$ if $(p,k)=1$. Without using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, is it possible to prove this?

I'm thinking of using the following steps:

1. By expressing $p\choose k$ as $\frac{p(p-1)!}{(p-k)!k!}$, we can show p that $p\choose k$ is a multiple of p, and the statement is immediately true.
2. But problem is I don't know if $\frac{(p-1)!}{(p-k)!k!}$ is a fraction, in which case I will be wrong.

Comment: Is $p$ prime? ${}$

Comment: Okay, but *could* $p$ be prime? Your answer isn't clear. Also: please reserve the symbol $p$ for primes in future.

Comment: What's $m$? ${}$

Comment: @Shaun sorry it's a typo. I mean k instead (close to m on the keyboard).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost there!
Use $$k{p\choose k} =p\frac{(p-1)!}{(p-k)!(k-1)!}$$
and the fact that the right-hand side is $p$ times another binomial coefficient.

Comment: But wouldn't that only show $k {p \choose k}$ is a multiple of p?

Comment: Yes! And that's when you use the coprimality of p and k.

Comment: If p divides ab and is coprime with a then p divides b.

Comment: It still feels like not fulfilling the "without using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic" requirement, good answer nevertheless ...

Comment: @rtybase you don't use the FTA to prove Euclid's lemma, rather the other way around. To prove Euclid's lemma all you need is Euclidean division.

Comment: Euclid's lemma is when $p$ is prime http://rtybase.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/alternative-definition-for-prime.html

Comment: See this proof for instance https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma#Proof

Comment: Yes, but ... Bézout's lemma is proved using what? Which again, it still feels like not fulfilling the "without using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic" requirement ... it's a chicken and egg situation.

Comment: Not at all, Bézout's lemma is proved using the extended Euclidean algorithm and the fact that the GCD of a and b is the least positive number that can be written ap+bq for some p and q, and also the only one of these integers that divides both a and b.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\binom{p}{k}=\frac pk\binom{p-1}{k-1}
$$
If $(p,k)=1$, [Bezout's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) says there are $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so that
$$
px+ky=1
$$
Then
$$
\binom{p}{k}=p\left[y\binom{p-1}{k-1}+x\binom{p}{k}\right]
$$

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean that $p$ is a prime number. Remind that if $p \wedge a=1$ and $p\wedge b=1$ then $p \wedge (ab)=1$. ( follows from Bezout's theorem )

Remark that
$$
k!\binom{p}{k}=p\left(p-1\right) \dots \left(p-k+1\right)
$$
Hence
$$
p  \ | \ k!\binom{p}{k}
$$
Using that $p \wedge k=1$ for all $k \in [1,p]$ then $p \wedge k!=1$.
Using Gauss's theorem

> $$
> p \ | \ \binom{p}{k}
> $$

Comment: $p$ is not a prime.